# What Big Data product or platform can I use to store geographical data?

Tags: location, geospatial, bigdata, sqlgeography

I'm looking for a Big Data solution for storing records with geographical locations (Lat/Lng), and then performing a proximity search.

For instance, storing all buildings in a database, and then querying it for the buildings closest to the user's current location.

I expect a large amount of entities with a lot of insertions, so this has to be a Big Data solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) with [PostGIS](http://postgis.refractions.net/). PostgreSQL is known as very good for handling large datasets. And, it is open source.

Comment: Doesn't 'Big Data' suggest he's looking for a cloud based solution?

Comment: He didn't mention this. Maybe someone will suggest also a cloud platform, or he might specify the question.